# Can CSS check if the element is breaking?

Tags: css

Is there a way to check(in CSS) if an element is breaking/new lining?
I can't know the width of the divs or the parent. I only want to know the first element after the break, so I can add special CSS to this element

Like this:

```
<div>
  first
</div>    
<div>
  second
</div>  
<div>
  third
</div>  
<div>
  fourth
</div>
```

the css:

```
div {
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
}
div:not(:first-child) {
    padding-left:10px;
}
```

here i need a check if the element is on a new line so I can remove the padding :

```
div:first-after-break {
    padding-left:0;
}
```

Comment: I believe that you're looking for the [`text-indent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-indent) CSS property.\

Comment: What do you mean with `div:not(:first)`? `:first` doesn't exist and `:not` support is still quite flakey (especially unsupported by IE <9). And where exactly do you want to know it's breaking. Inside on of the divs or between the divs if both are floating?

Comment: I actually made a typo, I should have been :first-child

Comment: I added some more explanation, because it was unclear what I really wanted

Answer (score 4):

I think in this case, you could probably do this by using `padding-right` to separate your elements, instead of `padding-left`. That way, elements are not indented when they start on a new line. If `padding-right` causes problems at the end of the line, you could consider using the `:last-child` pseudo selector ([more information about `:last-child`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html)), and set `padding-right: 0;` there.

This doesn't discard the question, though. I can think of legitimate uses of the `:first-after-break` pseudo you describe. For example: a fully responsive layout using floating block-level elements. In such a case, one might want to know if an element is at the left of the window.

Comment: That does fix my problem, but as you say it does not discard what I really want to achieve with this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `::first-line` pseudo element to get the first line of a div. If you want to apply style rules to lines that are *not* the first line, you could apply those styles to the whole element and then remove it from the first line. But if you want to specifically use the `padding` property, you could also set `text-indent` on the whole element (without any pseudo elements).

Comment: I added some more explanation, because it was unclear what I really wanted

Comment: @Lg102 It *only* works on block level elements, because the pseudo element is applied on the element that contains multiple lines, not on elements within these lines.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think there's a way in CSS to do what you're asking.

A DIV automatically takes up the full width of it's parent unless a width is specified since it's a BLOCK level element so if no width is specified so your second DIV would be on a new line anyway.